# Why the second run of `print(list(reader))` prints nothing?

Tags: python

```
>>> import csv
>>> csvfile = open("name.csv")
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=" ")
>>> print(list(reader))
[{'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'}, {'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'}, {'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'}]
>>> print(list(reader))
[]
```

I wonder why the second run of `print(list(reader))` prints nothing?
Has `reader` been changed after the first run of `print(list(reader))`? Thanks.

Comment: Because `reader` is a generator. After you iterate over it once, you cannot iterate over it again.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator

Answer (score 2):

Because `csv.DictReader()` returns a generator.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   csvfile.